# Annoying Blue Highlighting around div after click

Tags: html, css

[image]

When I click on the tab button im left with this annoying blue highlight around the div... Ive read in other forums that I should add the following to divs with this problem, but it is not working.

```
            .noSelect {
                -webkit-user-select: none;
                -khtml-user-select: none;
                -moz-user-select: none;
                -o-user-select: none;
                user-select: none;
            }
```

You can get a closer look here http://omarhabash.com/nova/?page_id=28

Comment: Please DO NOT link to external resources that can change. It ruins the value of your question to others. See: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: @Diodeus Well, in this case he included an image and some code, and then for additional reference he added the link.  So it's a lot better then just including the link.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add this to your css file!

```
.btn-group-justified > .btn-group .btn {
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
Always use this every time to avoid these kind of issues.

```
*:focus {
outline: 0;
outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this class:

```
.noSelect {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
    -moz-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
    -o-tap-highlight-color:transparent;
    tap-highlight-color:transparent;
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 7):

That appears to be the outline. It is default browser functionality for accessibility. You can change the style using the `outline` property.

*Something like this for example:*

```
.class {
    outline:none;
}
```

**Some Resources:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline
- http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/
- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html

**Demo:**

Press tab and you will see the outline when you tab over the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/gzmnbfem/

**Outline Removed Demo:**

Press tab and you will see no outline. However this is not a recommended approach as it breaks accessibility.

http://jsfiddle.net/gzmnbfem/1/